# .pth file not working in Python 3.5

Tags: python, path, pth

I'm using Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I save my python files in `/home/me/Python` and I would like to use a .pth-file to make python search that directory, so I created `custompaths.pth` and entered /home/me/Python on line 1.

I've tried saving `custompaths.pth` in several different directories, all of which are in `sys.path`, but if I try to import a module (`testmod.py`) located in `/home/me/Python` I just get:

```
ImportError: No module named 'testmod'
```

I have tried saving `testmod.py` in the same directories where I've tried `custompaths.pth` and then it imports just fine.

I have also tried different ways of entering the search path in `custompaths.pth`:

```
/home/me/Python/  
/home/me/Python  
home/me/Python  
home/me/Python/  
'/home/me/Python/'
```

Am I missing something here?